# Concat two rows of a CSV file

Tags: python, algorithm, dataframe, concatenation, rows

I am trying to clean data in a dataframe in python, where I am to concatenate Rows in which data in two columns(name, phone_no) are similar i.e.

I have

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTArW.png)

Trying to get

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFv1w.png)

Comment: Load the CSV into a dataframe, and use panda's `.groupby()` feature to combine related rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S It would be much better if you could provide a sample of the dataset instead of the images. Next time you can use `df.to_clipboard` and paste it as a code snippet in the question for reproducibility.

Now to the answer. You can use pandas `groupby` and then a custom aggregation.

First I created a dataset for the example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c"], "B": list(map(str, range(5))), "C": list(map(str, range(5, 10)))})
```

Looks as follows

```
   A  B  C
0  a  0  5
1  b  1  6
2  a  2  7
3  b  3  8
4  c  4  9
```

Then you can contact rows with similar keys (in your case the keys are `name` and `phone_no`

```py
gdf = df.groupby("A").agg({
    "B": ",".join,
    "C": ",".join
})
print(gdf)
```

And the results are as follows:

```
   A    B    C
0  a  0,2  5,7
1  b  1,3  6,8
2  c    4    9
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. And next time I will make sure to include sample of the dataset instead.